# Issues with signing APK with keystore.jks, built with ionic cordova

Tags: android, angular, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I build my app with the following line

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

This creates an 'app-release-unsigned.apk' file. I have a 'keystore.jks' file available and although everywhere I find people talking about .keystore files, I assume this is the file I need to sign it.

Following things I tried:

#### 1. Build with a build.json file

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release --BuildConfig=build.json
```

Json content:

```
{
  "android":
  {
    "release":
    {
      "keystore": "keystore.jks",
      "storePassword": "************", // Filled in password
      "password" : "************", // Filled in password
      "alias" : "**" // Also tried removing this line, didn't make any difference
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:** There build was still unsigned. (I tried also solving this with option 2)

#### 2. Sign apk with jarsigner command

I tried executing the following command at the root of my app, where the keystore file is placed as well.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore keystore.jks platforms/android/app/build/release/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk bp
```

**Problem:** after this command, it asks for `Enter Passphrase for keystore`. I tried filling in my password and storepassword, but then I get the error `jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

I also tried running the jarsigner command with keypass and storepass as flags, but that also didn't work.
I'm pretty sure my password is correct.

Lastly I see you could use Android Studio to build a generated APK. Only this option is not available to me in the Android Studio build menu. I'm using SDK Api level 28.

**TL;DR:** Can't build signed app, have no clue why.

Comment: Try `ionic cordova build android --prod --release --buildConfig build.json --verbose`

Comment: @Yatinpatel it builds and I get an APK in my `platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk` folder. It is still unsigned though..

Answer (score 2):

Could you try build using command line and `apksigner` :

Download latest platform-tools/build-tools from Android Studio

`File --> Settings --> Android SDK --> SDK Tools --> Download platform-tools`

It will contain `apksigner` (be sure you have recent JDK at least > 11 to use it, or you'll have errors)

Then open terminal :
`cd Project/android`

`gradlew assembleRelease`

`cd android\app\build\outputs\apk\release`

Add your `keystore.jks` file here.

In this repository, do :

`call zipalign -v -p 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release-unsigned-aligned.apk`

And then :

```
call apksigner sign --ks keystore.jks --ks-pass pass:YOURPASSWORD --key-pass pass:YOURPASSWORD --out app-release-signed.apk app-release-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

Then you have your signed apk. I'm using this way to deliver my APK to clients.

Comment: I get your answer is for React? Since your project setup is somewhat different. Does this work for angular projects in the same way?

Comment: This is the way I build for my Angular Project. I met problems using jarsigner so I moved to apksigner